# Get total of rows in a mysql table grouped by months and years

Tags: mysql, date, count, group-by, sum

I'd like to create some statistics and I want to them in an array grouped by months and years.

Got an MySQL `table_users` with column `user_id`.
I want build up a mysql query to list how many members we had in total at the end of each month. The result of the query should be:

```
 Year:   Month:    Members:
 --------------------------
 2014     12        11345
 2015      1        17939
 2015      2        25003
 2015      3        32667
```

There is also the column `user_signupdate` with the UNIX timestamp when the user_id was added. Whatever I've tried so far, I'm getting only the growing of user_id's, but I'd like to get the total of all user_id's we had for each month and year.

Is it possible to count and group this with only one MySQL query?

Comment: Provide some sample data with your table definition

Comment: SELECT COUNT(user_id) FROM table_users ORDER BY user_signupdate DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will perform simple arithmetic calculation to generate the members running total.  See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fb7b6/16/0).

```
select 
t1.year,
t1.month,
(@rtotal := @rtotal + t1.members) AS members
from 
(select year(user_signupdate) as year, month(user_signupdate) as month, count(user_id) as members
from table_users
group by year(user_signupdate), month(user_signupdate)
order by year(user_signupdate), month(user_signupdate)) as t1, (Select @rtotal:=0) as rt
```

Comment: This is gives me the result of how many ids are new in each month, but looking for the total of all new ids including the existing ids from previous months.

Comment: Your demo works and gives the result I wanted. However, when I apply then I get a syntax error. Do I need any special mysql settings to be allowed to SET @rtotal variable?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select t1.year, t1.month, (@rtotal := @rtotal + t1.members) AS members from'

Comment: SET @rtotal:=0;  ... When I remove this, the query runs without error, but of course missing the total value in the result.

Comment: Moved the Set @rtotal to body of the query.  Also updated demo. By chance are you using PHP?

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works, but check out your typing mistake at the end of the code: , ,